# How to print char *

Tags: c, pointers, char, printf, c-strings

I am trying to print char * name;

I have tried that

```
fprintf(stderr,"%c",* name)
```

But it doesn't seem to work. My reasoning was that since name is a character pointer I could use * to get the value for the pointer.

It gives the error
error: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char'

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" isn't a very useful diagnostic aid. What *does* it do?

Comment: "It gives the error error: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char'" I don't see how you can get that error message for the code you've posted. The `%c` format specifier implies the type `char`, not `char*`. That message would only make sense if you used `%s` instead of `%c` (or you used `%c` with `(f)scanf` instead of `(f)printf`).

Comment: Are you trying to print a character or a string? If `name` is a `char *`, then `*name` is a `char`, that is, a single character. Also, `%c` is the format specifier for a character. What exactly are you trying to print?

Comment: The issue has been resolved. The first answer below solved my issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you are

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *name = "TriposG";

    fprintf( stderr, "%s", name );

    return 0;
}
```

As for this statement

```
fprintf( stderr, "%c", *name);
```

then it outputs the first character of the string pointed to by the pointer `name`.

Answer (score 2):

If `name` is a `char*`, you only need to use `fprintf(stderr,"%s",name);`.